# PyTorch: Multi-class segmentation loss value != 0 when using target image as the prediction

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I was performing semantic segmentation using PyTorch. There are a total of 103 different classes in the dataset and the targets are RGB images with only the **Red** channel containing the labels. I was using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` as my loss function. For sanity, I wanted to check if using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` is correct for this problem and whether it has the expected behaviour

I pick a random mask from my dataset and create a categorical version of it using this custom transform

```
class ToCategorical:
    def __init__(self, n_classes: int) -> None:
        self.n_classes = n_classes

    def __call__(self, sample: torch.Tensor):
        mask = sample.permute(1, 2, 0)
        categories = torch.unique(mask).tolist()[1:]  # get all categories other than 0
        # build a tensor with `n_classes` channels
        one_hot_image = torch.zeros(self.n_classes, *mask.shape[:-1])
        for category in categories:
            # get spacial locs where the categ is present
            rows, cols, _ = torch.where(mask == category)
            # in same spacial loc but in `categ` channel fill 1
            one_hot_image[category, rows, cols] = 1  
        return one_hot_image
```

And then I send this image as the output (prediction) and use the ground truth mask as the target to the loss function.

```
import torch.nn as nn

mask = T.PILToTensor()(Image.open("path_to_image").convert("RGB"))
categorical_mask = ToCategorical(103)(mask).unsqueeze(0)
mask = mask[0].unsqueeze(0)  # get only the red channel, add fake batch_dim

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

target = mask
output = categorical_mask

print(output.shape, target.shape)
print(loss_fn(output, target.to(torch.long)))
```

I expected the loss to be zero but to my surprise, the output is as follows

```
torch.Size([1, 103, 600, 800]) torch.Size([1, 600, 800])
tensor(4.2836)
```

I verified with other samples in the dataset and I obtained similar values for other masks as well. Am I doing something wrong? I expect the loss to be = 0 when the output is the same as the target.

PS. I also know that `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` is the same as using `log_softmax` followed by `nn.NLLLoss()` but even I obtained the same value by using nllloss as well

### For Reference

Dataset used: [UECFoodPixComplete](https://mm.cs.uec.ac.jp/uecfoodpix/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to adress this:

> I expect the loss to be = 0 when the output is the same as the target.

If the prediction matches the target, *i.e.* the prediction corresponds to a one-hot-encoding of the labels contained in the dense target tensor, but the loss itself is not supposed to equal to zero. Actually, it can never be equal to zero because the [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) function is always positive by *definition*.

Let us take a minimal example with number of `#C` classes and a target `y_pred` and a prediction `y_pred` consisting of *prefect* predictions:

As a quick reminder:

- The *softmax* is applied on the logits (`q_i`) as `p_i = log(exp(q_i)/sum_j(exp(q_j))`:

  ```
  >>> p = F.softmax(y_pred, 1)
  ```

  Similarly if you are using the *log-softmax*, defined as `logp_i = log(p_i)`:

  ```
  >>> logp = F.log_softmax(y_pred, 1)
  ```
- Then comes the *negative likelihood* function computed between `x` the input and y the target: `-y*x`. In association with the *softmax*, it comes down to `-y*p`, or `-y*logp` respectively. In any case, whether you apply the log or not, only the predictions corresponding to the true classes will remain since the others ones are zeroed-out.

---

That being said, applying the `NLLLoss` on `y_pred` would indeed result with a `0` as you expected in your question. However, here we apply it on the probability distribution or log-probability: `p`, or `logp` respectively!

In our specific case, `p_i = 1` for the true class and *p_i = 0* for all other classes (there are `#C - 1` of those). This means the *softmax* of the logit associated with the true class will equal to `exp(1)/sum_i(p_i)`. And since `sum_i(p_i) = (#C-1)*exp(0) + exp(1)`. We therefore have:

```
softmax(p) = e / (#C - 1 + e)
```

Similarly for *log-softmax*:

```
log-softmax(p) = log(e / (#C-1 + e)) = 1 - log(#C - 1 + e)
```

If we proceed by applying the negative likelihood function we simply get `cross-entropy(y_pred, y_true) = (nllloss o log-softmax)(y_pred, y_true)`. This results in:

```
loss = - (1 - log(#C - 1 + e)) = log(#C - 1 + e) - 1
```

This effectively corresponds to the minimum of the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` function.

---

Regarding your specific case where `#C = 103`, you may have an issue in your code... since the average loss should equal to `log(102 + e) - 1` *i.e.* around `3.65`.

```
>>> y_true = torch.randint(0,103,(1,1,2,5))
>>> y_pred = torch.zeros(1,103,2,5).scatter(1, y_true, value=1)
```

You can see for yourself with one of the provided methods:

- the builtin function [`nn.functional.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy.html#torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy):

  ```
  >>> F.cross_entropy(y_pred, y_true[:,0])
  tensor(3.6513)
  ```
- manually computing the quantity:

  ```
  >>> logp = F.log_softmax(y_pred, 1)
  >>> -logp.gather(1, y_true).mean()
  tensor(3.6513)
  ```
- analytical result:

  ```
  >>> log(102 + e) - 1
  3.6513
  ```